# Vue - use Events, Event Bus, or Vuex for showing components

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm currently building a larger scale vue application. For global state management I use vuex of course. However, I came across the question of how to show or hide really simple components. For example I have a navbar which can open up a bug form modal component. I also have a sidebar component which can be either visible or non-visible. From within these components I want to be able to close them in the parent. Own mutations in vuex seem a little bit overkill for simply toggling the visibility of a child component, also I don't want the store to get bloated by these things.

My question now is, how I should handle showing these components. I can think of 3 different solutions:

1) Use solely Vuex for everything, with own actions, getters and methods for showing or hiding simple components.

2) Use an Event Bus to show these components along with vuex for storing user data like email for example

3) Just emitting events in the child component and listening to it in parent component

Comment: This is marked (rightfully) as too subjective. IMO if you're going to use Vuex, you should stick to that exclusively. Anything else you do (event buses and whatnot) won't be in sync with Vuex state, which defeats (some of) the purpose. If you're worried about the bloat in Vuex state, maybe just use Vuex modules to split it up.